# Temperature Conversion: String Input to Double

Tags: java, string, user-interface, type-conversion

// Im trying to use a GUI program to convert temperature. I've used a a JTextField for the user to input a string of numbers so I can convert that string field in to a double then use that double for the formula and then convert it back to string. I am required to used two different methods for both of the conversion. I am have an error on my conversion methods for the following lines:

```
c = double.parseDouble(userInput); 
f = (c * 9 / 5) + 32);
```

&

```
f = double.parseDouble(userInput);
c = (f * 9 / 5) + 32);
```

Here is my code:

```
public Temperature() {
    super( "Temperature Converter" ) ;
    setSize( HEIGHT, WIDTH ) ;
    setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE ) ;

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel() ;
    panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,5));

    labelC = new JLabel("Celsius:");
    panel1.add(labelC);

    textFieldC = new JTextField( "Enter Here") ;
    panel1.add(textFieldC) ;

    labelEquals = new JLabel("=");
    panel1.add(labelEquals);

    textFieldAnswerF = new JTextField( "Answer") ;
    panel1.add(textFieldAnswerF) ;

    convertC2F = new JButton( "C to F") ;
    panel1.add(convertC2F) ;

    labelF = new JLabel("Fahrenheit:");
    panel1.add(labelF);

    textFieldF = new JTextField( "Enter Here") ;
    panel1.add(textFieldF) ;

    labelEquals = new JLabel("=");
    panel1.add(labelEquals);

    textFieldAnswerC = new JTextField( "Answer") ;
    panel1.add(textFieldAnswerC) ;

    convertF2C = new JButton( "F to C") ;
    panel1.add(convertF2C) ;

    add(panel1) ;

} // Temperature constructor

/**
    Method to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit
*/
public double fahrenheit(double f, double c){
    String  userInput = textFieldC.getText();
    c = double.parseDouble(userInput); 
    f = (c * 9 / 5) + 32);
    textFieldAnswerF.setText("" + f);
}

/**
    Method to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius
*/
public double celsius(double c, double f){
    String  userInput = textFieldF.getText();
    f = double.parseDouble(userInput);
    c = (f * 9 / 5) + 32);
    textFieldAnswerC.setText("" + c);
}
```

Here are my errors:

```
Temperature.java:87: error: class expected
    c = double.parseDouble(userInput);
               ^
Temperature.java:87: error: ';' expected
    c = double.parseDouble(userInput);
                          ^
Temperature.java:87: error: not a statement
    c = double.parseDouble(userInput);
                           ^
Temperature.java:87: error: ';' expected
    c = double.parseDouble(userInput);
                                    ^
Temperature.java:88: error: ';' expected
    f = (c * 9 / 5) + 32);
                        ^
Temperature.java:97: error: class expected
    f = double.parseDouble(userInput);
               ^
Temperature.java:97: error: ';' expected
    f = double.parseDouble(userInput);
                          ^
Temperature.java:97: error: not a statement
    f = double.parseDouble(userInput);
                           ^
Process javac exited with code 1
Temperature.java:97: error: ';' expected
    f = double.parseDouble(userInput);
                                    ^
Temperature.java:98: error: ';' expected
    c = (f * 9 / 5) + 32);
                        ^
10 errors
```

Comment: What's the error message?  That's actually important, you know...

Comment: I've put my error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is case sensitive. Use

```
f = Double.parseDouble(userInput);
```

In addition remove the extra parenthesis from the second statement in both cases:

```
c = (f * 9 / 5) + 32;
                    ^
```

Comment: thanks, I've fixed everything but it's asking for a return statement. What should I put as a return?

Comment: if I return c, wouldn't that only give me the double and not the string? I need to return a string so it displays a string in my JTextField

Comment: then use `Double.toString` on the return value

Comment: What do you mean? How is that suppose to look like in my program? my last lines in the method is                                                            c = (f - 32) * 5/9;                          textFieldAnswerC.setText("" + c);
  return c;

Comment: Don't set the text in the method itself. Do it from an `ActionListener` or whereever the code is called

Answer (score 0):

The Celsius conversion formula is **incorrect**.  It's c = (f - 32) * (5/9).  Try

```
c = (f - 32) * 5 / 9;
```

With both of your formulas, you have an extra, unmatched `)` at the end; remove them.

Answer (score 0):

`double` is a primitive type while `Double` is a wrapper class which has methods. In your case you're using double and calling methods on it which is invalid.

Therefore use `Double`.